# Blinking LED with ESP IDF on ESP32 board disabling watchdog reset

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

so i'm still new to developing on ESP 32 board using ESP IDF. I recently got an assignment to create a sequentially blinking 3 led (1 second each) without the FreeRTOS library or any other built in delay function.

**This is my current code (ESP IDF 5.0.1) :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>
#include "driver/gpio.h"

#define LED_PIN_A GPIO_NUM_18
#define LED_PIN_B GPIO_NUM_19
#define LED_PIN_C GPIO_NUM_21

void delay_t(uint32_t time){
    int i, j;
    double x = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 30000; j++) {
            x += sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(i + j)));
        }
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    esp_task_wdt_init(30,false);
    gpio_set_direction(LED_PIN_A, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT); 
    gpio_set_direction(LED_PIN_B, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT); 
    gpio_set_direction(LED_PIN_C, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT); 
    while(true)
    {
        esp_task_wdt_init(30,false);
        gpio_set_level(LED_PIN_A, 1);         // Turn the LED on
        delay_t(1);
        gpio_set_level(LED_PIN_A, 0);         // Turn the LED off
        gpio_set_level(LED_PIN_B, 1);         // Turn the LED on
        delay_t(1);
        gpio_set_level(LED_PIN_B, 0);         // Turn the LED off
        gpio_set_level(LED_PIN_C, 1);         // Turn the LED on
        delay_t(1);
        gpio_set_level(LED_PIN_C, 0);         // Turn the LED off
}  

}
```

**I got this watchdog error**

```
E:/tugas/ugm/esp32/blinkledtes/main/main.c:24:23: warning: passing argument 1 of 'esp_task_wdt_init' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   24 |     esp_task_wdt_init(30,false);
      |                       ^~
      |                       |
      |                       int
In file included from E:/tugas/ugm/esp32/blinkledtes/main/main.c:3:
C:/Users/Ilyas/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include/esp_task_wdt.h:47:58: note: expected 'const esp_task_wdt_config_t *' but argument is of type 'int'
   47 | esp_err_t esp_task_wdt_init(const esp_task_wdt_config_t *config);
      |                             ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
E:/tugas/ugm/esp32/blinkledtes/main/main.c:24:5: error: too many arguments to function 'esp_task_wdt_init'
   24 |     esp_task_wdt_init(30,false);
      |     ^~~~~~~
In file included from E:/tugas/ugm/esp32/blinkledtes/main/main.c:3:
C:/Users/Ilyas/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include/esp_task_wdt.h:47:11: note: declared here   
   47 | esp_err_t esp_task_wdt_init(const esp_task_wdt_config_t *config);
      |           ^~~~~~~
E:/tugas/ugm/esp32/blinkledtes/main/main.c:30:27: warning: passing argument 1 of 'esp_task_wdt_init' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   30 |         esp_task_wdt_init(30,false);
      |                           ^~
      |                           |
      |                           int
In file included from E:/tugas/ugm/esp32/blinkledtes/main/main.c:3:
C:/Users/Ilyas/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include/esp_task_wdt.h:47:58: note: expected 'const esp_task_wdt_config_t *' but argument is of type 'int'
   47 | esp_err_t esp_task_wdt_init(const esp_task_wdt_config_t *config);
      |                             ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
E:/tugas/ugm/esp32/blinkledtes/main/main.c:30:9: error: too many arguments to function 'esp_task_wdt_init'
   30 |         esp_task_wdt_init(30,false);
      |         ^~~~~~~
In file included from E:/tugas/ugm/esp32/blinkledtes/main/main.c:3:
C:/Users/Ilyas/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/include/esp_task_wdt.h:47:11: note: declared here   
   47 | esp_err_t esp_task_wdt_init(const esp_task_wdt_config_t *config);
      |           ^~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1, output of the command is in the e:\tugas\ugm\esp32\blinkledtes\build\log\idf_py_stderr_output_17876 and e:\tugas\ugm\esp32\blinkledtes\build\log\idf_py_stdout_output_17876
```

So, at first i tried to flash my program to the board without the esp_task_wdt_init() but it says in the terminal that my watchdog timer got triggered thus only 1 led turn on. Then, i read that i should add the esp_task_wdt_init(30, false) so that it will set the watchdog timeout to 30 second and disable the controller reset if it’s triggered. But after i add it to my code, i get the error. If i'm using vTaskDelay for the LED delay, everything is working perfectly fine. But the assignment says not to use the FreeRTOS library or any other delay function.